# why does Xcode convert my Integers into Floats without me assigning it to do so?

Tags: swift, integer, tuples

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EQcyz.png)I am reading swift apprentice third edition where its teaching me to use tuples. When I type in the code from the book into my playground the result seems to become a float number instead of an integer. I googled it and could not get an answer so I opened up another playground (because I had a lot of previous code in that playground) and typed it in there but the same thing happened. I am completely new to swift so any help would be great.

Comment: Please post code and output as text, not pictures.

Comment: Those are locations it is not converted in Float

Answer (score 3):

there is no problem its Int not double  it just `playground  syntax of tuple element location`

if tuple have 2 element say

`var tuple = (1,3)`   so you can access it tuple.0 =1, tuple.1 = 3    its syntax

element in tuple at 0 =  1  , element in tuple at index 1 = 3  so playground write it 0 = 1  , 1 = 3

`var tuple = (1,3,6)`

tuple.0  = 1  , tuple.1 = 3, tuple.2 = 6     --> element at index 0 = 1 , element at index 1= 3 , element at index 2 = 6

```
var person = ("John", "Smith")

var firstName = person.0 // John
var lastName = person.1 // Smith
```

Answer (score 1):

That is swift syntax. Its index start from 0 like array index. But if we want to use as our key, we can define it.

```
let person = (firstName:"Seyha",lastName:"Hiem")

person.firstName

person.lastName
```